# C#: Leer archivo XML con NameSpace

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Quiero obtener los valores de estos nodos de un archivo `XML` y cada uno de estos valores asignarle una variable.

Obtengo el archivo de esta forma:

**CODE:**

```
var miXML = File.ReadAllText("D:\\20101284981-01-0002-0000000060.xml");
```

**XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
    <ar:ApplicationResponse xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ApplicationResponse-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">

    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:CustomizationID>1.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ID>201200000230061</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2012-06-12</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>10:09:27</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:ResponseDate>2012-06-12</cbc:ResponseDate>
    <cbc:ResponseTime>10:09:30</cbc:ResponseTime>
    <cbc:Note>4031 - Debe indicar el nombre comercial</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:Note>4001 - El numero de RUC del receptor no existe.</cbc:Note>

    <ar:ApplicationResponse>
```

*Probé con XDocument y luego declarar los XNamespace pero cuando hago un xdoc.load("C:// .... "); se cae y me manda un error [ 'ar' es un prefijo no declarado. línea 2, posición 2.]*

Comment: y que es lo que probaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Probé con XDocument y luego declarar los XNamespace pero  cuando hago un xdoc.load("C:// .... "); se cae y me manda un error [ 'ar' es un prefijo no declarado. línea 2, posición 2.]

Comment: podrias agregar toda esa info a la pregunta por favor. y no esta mal declarado el prefijo? falta declarar ar en el XML

Comment: Asi es, falta declarar pero de todas formas es un documento XML que no debo editar, lo importante aqui es obtener los valores de los nodos como por ejemplo: "2.0" del nodo <cbc:UBLVersionID>

Comment: el error que da es pq no puede parsearlo pq esta mal declarado.. entonces que quieres hacer?

Comment: Quiero saber como puedo poner el valor "2.0" (del ejemplo ya mencionado) en una variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu XML tiene dos errores:

1. No esta declarado el nameSpace AR
2. No se esta cerrando el tag ar:ApplicationResponse

Te muestro como lo arregle:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /*
        //XML corregido, agregar namespace ar, cerrar tag ar
        string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='no' ?>
                    <ar:ApplicationResponse xmlns='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ApplicationResponse-2'
                    xmlns:ar='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'
                    xmlns:cac='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2'
                    xmlns:cbc='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2'
                    xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'
                    xmlns:ext='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2'>
                    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
                    <cbc:CustomizationID>1.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
                    <cbc:ID>201200000230061</cbc:ID>
                    <cbc:IssueDate>2012-06-12</cbc:IssueDate>
                    <cbc:IssueTime>10:09:27</cbc:IssueTime>
                    <cbc:ResponseDate>2012-06-12</cbc:ResponseDate>
                    <cbc:ResponseTime>10:09:30</cbc:ResponseTime>
                    <cbc:Note>4031 - Debe indicar el nombre comercial</cbc:Note>
                    <cbc:Note>4001 - El numero de RUC del receptor no existe.</cbc:Note>
                    </ar:ApplicationResponse>";
                    */

        //Para arreglar tu XML

        string xmlMAL = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='no' ?>
                    <ar:ApplicationResponse xmlns='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ApplicationResponse-2'
                    xmlns:cac='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2'
                    xmlns:cbc='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2'
                    xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'
                    xmlns:ext='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2'>
                    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
                    <cbc:CustomizationID>1.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
                    <cbc:ID>201200000230061</cbc:ID>
                    <cbc:IssueDate>2012-06-12</cbc:IssueDate>
                    <cbc:IssueTime>10:09:27</cbc:IssueTime>
                    <cbc:ResponseDate>2012-06-12</cbc:ResponseDate>
                    <cbc:ResponseTime>10:09:30</cbc:ResponseTime>
                    <cbc:Note>4031 - Debe indicar el nombre comercial</cbc:Note>
                    <cbc:Note>4001 - El numero de RUC del receptor no existe.</cbc:Note>
                    <ar:ApplicationResponse>";

        string xml = xmlMAL;
        //Agrego el namespace AR
        xml = xml.Replace("<ar:ApplicationResponse ", "<ar:ApplicationResponse xmlns:ar='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' ");
        //Cierro el tag del <ar:ApplicationResponse>
        xml = xml.Replace("<ar:ApplicationResponse>", "</ar:ApplicationResponse>");

        var xmlInput = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var documento = LeerXML.Procesar(xmlInput);

        Console.WriteLine("UBLVersionID: " +documento.UBLVersionID.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("CustomizationID: " + documento.CustomizationID.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + documento.ID.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("IssueDate: " + documento.IssueDate.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("IssueTime: " + documento.IssueTime.ToShortTimeString());
        Console.WriteLine("ResponseDate: " + documento.ResponseDate.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("ResponseTime: " + documento.ResponseTime.ToShortTimeString());
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var n in documento.Notes) {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("Nota" + i.ToString() + ": " + n);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Cree la clase LeerXML:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace LeerXMLConNamespace

{
    public class LeerXML
{

    public static Documento Procesar(XDocument xml)
    {
        try
        {

            XNamespace cbc = @"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2";

            var doc = new Documento();


            //UBLVersionID
            var UBLVersionID = (from x in xml.Descendants(cbc + "UBLVersionID")
                                select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (UBLVersionID != null)
            {
                doc.UBLVersionID = decimal.Parse(UBLVersionID.Value == null ? "0.0" : UBLVersionID.Value.ToString());
            }
            //CustomizationID
            var CustomizationID = (from x in xml.Descendants(cbc + "CustomizationID")
                                select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (CustomizationID != null)
            {
                doc.CustomizationID = decimal.Parse(CustomizationID.Value == null ? "0.0" : CustomizationID.Value.ToString());
            }
            //CustomizationID
            var ID = (from x in xml.Descendants(cbc + "ID")
                                   select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ID != null)
            {
                doc.ID = Int64.Parse(ID.Value == null ? "0" : ID.Value.ToString());
            }
            //IssueDate
            var IssueDate = (from x in xml.Descendants(cbc + "IssueDate")
                      select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (IssueDate != null)
            {
                doc.IssueDate = DateTime.Parse(IssueDate.Value == null ? "1900-01-01" : IssueDate.Value.ToString());
            }
            //IssueTime
            var IssueTime = (from x in xml.Descendants(cbc + "IssueTime")
                             select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (IssueTime != null)
            {
                doc.IssueTime = DateTime.Parse(IssueTime.Value == null ? "1900-01-01" : "1900-01-01 " + IssueTime.Value.ToString());
            }
            //IssueDate
            var ResponseDate = (from x in xml.Descendants(cbc + "ResponseDate")
                             select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ResponseDate != null)
            {
                doc.ResponseDate = DateTime.Parse(ResponseDate.Value == null ? "1900-01-01" : ResponseDate.Value.ToString());
            }
            //IssueTime
            var ResponseTime = (from x in xml.Descendants(cbc + "ResponseTime")
                             select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ResponseTime != null)
            {
                doc.ResponseTime = DateTime.Parse(ResponseTime.Value == null ? "1900-01-01" : "1900-01-01 " + ResponseTime.Value.ToString());
            }
            //IssueTime
            var Notes = (from x in xml.Descendants(cbc + "Note")
                                select x).ToList();
            doc.Notes = new List<string>();
            foreach (var n in Notes)
            {
                doc.Notes.Add(n.Value ?? "");
            }             


            return doc;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Cree la entidad Documento, que contiene los datos del XML:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LeerXMLConNamespace
{
    public class Documento
    {
        public decimal UBLVersionID { get; set; }
        public decimal CustomizationID { get; set; }
        public Int64 ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime IssueTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ResponseDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ResponseTime { get; set; }
        public List<string> Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo te anexo la aplicación de ejemplo que hice:
[Ejemplo leer XML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1NrUmB-KIz6dU1Zck1JQ09DQnc)

Comment: Muchas gracias Cristina, es lo que necesitada (parsear el xml y adaptarlo). Funciona bien ♥